Insomnia: Using same uuid in url and in post request body
I need to generate an insomnia request where url has a param like this <host_url>/<api>/<id> and post body has JSON like this
data: {
  myId: <id>
}

<id> has to be randomly generated UUID and needs to be same in both url path and post request body.
I tried using {% uuid 'v4' %} in both the places but it seems to use different values for both of them. How can I make sure that both have same UUIDs?
